# Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality definition meaning

Tags: linear-algebra, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

In Linear algebra, I have an inequality theorem that states, "If $x$ and $y$ are vectors in an inner product space $V$, then
$$\langle x,y\rangle^{2} \leqslant \langle x,x\rangle\langle y,y\rangle$$
I don't seem to understand the point of this theorem. What does it mean? and how is it useful?

Comment: You can use it to prove that non-commuting quantum observables imply those observables imply a corresponding uncertainty principle. There's a great many other proofs that use it.

Comment: Intuitively, this result tells you that that inner product space automatically has a reasonable notion of an "angle" between two vectors. In particular, we can always define
$$
\theta = \cos^{-1} \left(\frac{\langle x,y \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle \langle y,y \rangle}} \right)
$$
(and we take the real part of the numerator for complex inner product spaces)

Comment: Wikipedia has a [brief list of applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Applications).

Comment: It is very useful. For example you can use it for maximzing the function $f(x,y,w,z)=xw+yz$ under  conditions $x^2+y^2=1,$ $w^2+z^2=1$ without using the Lagrange multipliers. Besides take a  look at my last name.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most useful things that can be deduced from Cauchy's inequality is the triangle inequality: If $x, y \in V$, then $\|x + y\| \leq \|x\| + \|y\|$.